# Linear Mixed Models and time autocorrelation for Panel Data in Python Statsmodels

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, mixed-models, panel-data

I am looking at shifts among salespeople at a bakesale, trying to see if there is a substantial difference between a salesperson's sales during different hours of their shift.  Specifically, I am trying to evaluate a) if the trend is significant between individual shift hours, and b) how this ranks relative to a few other potential explanatory variables.

The data set has multiple shifts per salesperson of the same length, divided by hour.

E.g.

```
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula("Cookies ~ C(Hour) + CustomerArrivals + Oventemp", BakeSaleData, groups=BakeSaleData["Salesperson"])
result = model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

[Our Q-Q plot for the residuals:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esb6U.png)

I was told by someone reviewing my research with a considerably greater background in statistics that there was substantial autocorrelation in my model, but it's not clear to me how to compensate for this.

I know that in a traditional time series dataset, we can use AR(1) and Cochrane-Orcutt to factor in autocorrelation terms, but those time series calculations are generally on datasets where there is a single time series.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what violation of independent errors you're trying to account for here. In a TS framework, we assume that future observations are correlated with past observations `cor(e_t, e_{t+1}) != 0`. In MLM, we assume that observations within groups (in your case `Salesperson`'s) are correlated `cor(e_{i,j}, e{i,k}) != 0)` where `j != k`. Or are you also trying to control for correlated errors within shifts? Can you please rephrase / clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks for helping me to clarify the question - I guess the concern is that there could potentially be correlation between the individual hours that carries over (e.g. if high sales in a previous hour affect the current hour)...

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm not sure if this fit's in the MLM framework or not... why don't you test how severe a problem it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

statsmodels MixedLM doesn't allow for direct correlation of the residuals beyond the random coefficients or random effects.

You could use statsmodels.GEE which is a one way panel data model that allows for a larger range of correlation structures including AR(1). With family Gaussian it would be similar to MixedLM. However, it uses estimating equations which is similar to exactly identified GMM in econometrics, and GEE uses by default cluster robust standard errors. The assumption with serially correlated errors is that the explanatory variables are exogenous.

Here https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/wiki/Examples#generalized-estimating-equations-gee are some notebooks for GEE.

Standard econometrics panel data with Cochrane-Orcutt or Prais-Winston similar to Stata's are not yet included in statsmodels (although there might be a draft version lying around somewhere).

Comment: This has definitely helped. There seems to be substantially less deviation with the QQ plot, although the model parameters don't change too much relative to the MixedLM estimates.

Comment: The estimate of the parameters for the linear function are robust to misspecified variance and correlation in OLS or GLM (linear exponential family) in general. Only the standard errors and whether it is an efficient estimator is affected. (Cluster robust standard errors as in GEE are robust to any type of within cluster correlation.)